# How to Import Jar or Java code in Robot Framework use the methods defined in Java

Tags: robotframework, jython

I have followed all the steps provided in Link 
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/robot-framework-tutorial-writing-keyword-libraries-in-java/

- Folder Structure
- Running Jybot

Console:

C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>start_SampleLibrary_TestSuite.bat
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>del ......\output*.xml /Q
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>del ......\output*.html /Q
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>del ......\output*.png /Q
The system cannot find the file specified.
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>set CLASSPATH="....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;"....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;""
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>echo "....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;"....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;""
"....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;"....\lib\SampleLibrary.jar;""
C:\robot\execution\local\scripts>jybot --outputdir ......\output ......\implementation\testsuites\SampleLibraryTestsuite.html
[ ERROR ] Parsing '......\implementation\testsuites\SampleLibraryTestsuite.html' failed: Data source does not exist.

Any suggestions is appriciated !!

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/42384822/it+errors+when+specifying+the+user+defined+java+library+into+red+robot+framework+eclipse+editor

With reference to above blog, it worked !!!

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged on this site. You should at the very least summarize the article you are linking to.

Answer (score -3):

Why Java? RobotFramework is python wrapper, you can use python with all its library.
Easy to import:

```
Library    your/python/file/path.py
```

You can also execute a python line in one robot file

```
Evaluate    print("Hello word")
```

BTW you can make your java keyword and import it in robot. Tutorial here https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/robot-framework-tutorial-writing-keyword-libraries-in-java/

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your reply.  

In My Project, We need to use Java implemented Security Code and extend that code by JAR or Complete Project.

Hence, we need to integrate with Java Code base to Jython based Robot Framework.

Please do suggest, How we can achieve.

Comment: (Had you tried to make pip install robotframework from jython?) You can try to make robot believe it is python instead of jython. After jython installation put the jython's path in python's environment variable. Obv this is a test, if it works you have to clean your environment. Let me know, It's interesting